# zooming and point selection in Acinonyx

Tags: r, graphics, interactive

Standard R graphics are not particularly convenient for interactive zooming into large data sets. There's been some work with Qt for a new device, but I haven't seen a fully working example yet (pointers appreciated if I missed something).

That's how I came across [Acinonyx](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/Acinonyx/html/00Index.html); it is already at a usable stage, at least on OSX, and promises fast and interactive display.

Sadly, I cannot find examples to perform the following tasks:

- zoom in and out with mouse interaction
- display the coordinates of a selected point

I'm pretty sure both are possible / implemented, but the documentation is quite weak at the moment.

**Edit:** after playing around and going through iplot's documentation, it seems that the `command` and `ctrl` keys do what I wanted.
More generally, though, is there a possibility to extend the interactivity of Acinonyx with custom buttons? When hovering the top-left of the plot window, buttons appear, that depend on the plot type. I would like to create a new one for scatterplots, that would let the user select a curve and shift it vertically with the mouse.

Comment: OK, found the zoom: `command key + mouse`

Comment: and `ctrl key` brings a cross-hair with the mouse coordinates